# Report a listing of some fields from attribute table

Tags: list, reports

QGIS 3.22.4
For working purposes, I want to have a listing of some attributes in a shapefile (line), and have those information as a listing (multiple line per page). No geographic dat (maps,...) needed.
I tested layouts and reports, but when I add a text field, defined with the expression editor to point to one or more fields in the attribute file, I got one line per page, and not a real listing!
What should I do to achieve this listing type (multi line per page, multi page if needed).

Comment: Are you asking how to print or export the attribute table ?

Comment: To print only. Export to excel could be a workaround, but would prefer to stay in qgis and print a report, if possible

Comment: So I guess the way is to add an attribute table in your layout or report (Add Item>Add Attribute Table) configure it to your liking and print that...

Comment: I added the attribute table in my layout (I did not know this technique), but when I print, I just have the column titles and no data. What did I miss?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your setting, after using attribute table and choosing the right source data should appear and print...

Comment: IN the properties of the Table object I added to the layout , I defined the main properties as follows: Source as layer ENtities, Layer with the layer I want to report. THen the names of all the fields from the attribute table appered as a title line. As a first step, I let all the other parameters as default. I tried to click on the button "Update Table', but nothing changed and no data apperaed under the titles. I also tested a pdf export, but just the titles appeared!

Comment: OOps, during the test to answer the previous question, I noticed that the area defined fot the object was limited to one line.  I opened it, and "miracle", the data appeared. The problem is now that I can not put all the data on one page, and I have only one page printed ! What can I do to have the nulber of pages that are necessary for all the data I want to print (I have currently at least 2 pages, but still have data to feed in.

Comment: If the table content is more then one page, any idea how to handle that. I see no fonction génerating an automatic page break, and adapt automatically the number of pages necessary to print all the lines in the table